# Error accessing to the TSensorManager.Current in the POSIX-timer event handler

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, timer, android-sensors

```
Uses AndroidApi.Timer, System.Sensors;
```

I do not want to discharge the battery by the GPS sensor, cause in my Adnroid service I use POSIX-timer (AndroidTimerCreate). In it's event handler from time to time (every 5 mins) I am enabling and disabling LocationSensor.

When I refer to the property TSensorManager.Current:

```
TSensorManager.Current.Activate;
FSensors := SensorManager.Current.GetSensorsByCategory(TSensorCategory.Location);
```

I get the error:

```
Сan't start sensor: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

But if to execute this code in *AndroidServiceStartCommand* or *AndroidServiceCreate* methods, then *SensorManager* well activates.

For the test I transferred the code from service to Multi-Device Appplication — the trouble is still exists.

Help me plese with decision of the issue, how to enable and disable the LocationSensor in the timer (enable/disable every 5 minutes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that solution:

1. Create the filter for *LocalBroadcastManager* on the action *ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGE*, registering *LocalBroadcastReceiver*;
2. In the timer's event sending sendBroadcast the action *ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGE*;
3. In the handler *LocalBroadcastReceiver* switch *TLocationSensor's* property *Active*.

I spyed [the sulution here](http://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=7270), so good example.